# Browsing to dev.azure.com gives a connection was reset error

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-clone

I just received a new laptop and am in the process of cloning my repos through Visual Studio. I am able to clone from github without issue. When I attempt to connect to my azure repos I get the dreaded 'Recv failure: connection was reset' error. When I browse to the site, initially I get the same "connection was reset" error (from Edge and Chrome) for a few seconds and then something happens and the browser figures out what to do and suddenly everything is fine.

I am on a home network with no fancy settings. My older laptop does not have an issue so I don't think it's the router. I turned off McAfee and tried with the same results. I also tried running:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

I also tried with the Git App with the same result.

Comment: You should not set `http.sslVerify` to `false` because that lets anyone between you and the server compromise your connection and send you malicious data.

Comment: @Cef Can you check if the **Killer Network Service** exists in your **Local Machine -> Service**? If yes, you can try to disable it and check if it can work.

Comment: Wow that was it! What is that thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around for me was to connect with an ethernet connection instead of wireless. As per Kevin's suggestion turning off 'Killer Network Service' also resolves the issue. Killer Network service needs to be killed.